# An integral involving the Bose-Einstein distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration

I'm trying to reproduce the following calculation from the book by Fetter and Walecka (eq. 55.37 and following ones), which represents the temperature dependance of the non-condensate part of a weakly-interacting Bose gas:

$$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{u_k^2 + v_k^2}{e^{E_k/T} - 1} \approx \frac{m}{12 \pi c} T^2 $$

where $E_k=\sqrt{(k^2/2m + ng)^2 - (ng)^2}$, $v_k^2 = u_k^2 - 1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{k^2 / 2m - ng}{E_k} - 1 \right)$, $c=\sqrt{ng/m}$.

I don't know how this approximate result, valid for low-temperatures, is obtained, as it is not possible to expand the integrand in series of $T$ at $T=0$.

I would like to know how to re-obtain the result. All the standard techniques I tried did not work (substitutions, saddle point, etc...)

Comment: It would be nice, instead of "etc." to just list exactly what you tried. Also, if you really did try a saddle point approximation, why not include your work and the result in the post? It could save us some time if there's just an error in the approach.

Comment: I don't think I need to list every single way I know of solving an integral that didn't work in this case... Do I? As per site rules I would have shared relevant work which may be useful. Of course I do not share work which turned out to be useless, or which showed that the method does not work here.

However, as you ask, substitution does not work because, as the expression is not analytical in T there is no way of obtaining a T-expansion.

By definition the saddle point method is not applicable, as the integrand grows indefinitely and there is no point to saddle.

Comment: Do you think you can make the assumption that at low $T$, $e^{E_k/T} \gg 1$? This would allow you to get rid of the $-1$ in the denominator, which makes it seem (a bit) more tractable. Might be where the approximation comes in.

Comment: I thought of it, but I didn't use the approximation because when $k=0$ also $E_k = 0$ and the assumption doesn't hold.

However using it I'm able to obtain the result, so apparently that's the way to go, and there should be some argument according to which the low $k$ modes do not count.

Thank you very much!